# Parsing object in python

Tags: python, linkedin-api

```
{u'jobs': {u'_total': 301746, u'_count': 10, u'_start': 0, u'values': [{u'position':       {u'title': u'Director of Sales, New York '}, u'id': 7489651}, {u'position': {u'title': u'Senior Software Development Engineer'}, u'id': 7489610}, {u'position': {u'title': u'Senior Analyst, Marketing Analytics'}, u'id': 7489572}, {u'position': {u'title': u'Director,  Quantitative Analytics'}, u'id': 7489559}, {u'position': {u'title': u'Senior Quantitative Analyst'}, u'id': 7489542}, {u'position': {u'title': u'Director - Progam Lead and Project Manager - Collateral Management'}, u'id': 7489520}, {u'position': {u'title': u'Accounting and Finance Manager'}, u'id': 7489519}, {u'position': {u'title': u'Software Development Engineer - Test'}, u'id': 7489508}, {u'position': {u'title': u'Sr. Sales Executive - Technology'}, u'id': 7489462}, {u'position': {u'title': u'Recruitment Manager'}, u'id': 7489264}]}}
```

Hi, I'm really really new to scripting in general - db programmer. I'm trying to use a python linkedIN api that returns data formatted like above. Could someone please help me parse that data out; I would like to store data into some type of Python Data structure and then eventually write it into a database.

Comment: If you do `print type(data)` where data is what you received, what is returned?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Python interface to the LinkedIn API](https://github.com/ozgur/python-linkedin) has already returned you a python dict.

For example, you can extract a list of actual jobs from the data you've provided:

```
from pprint import pprint

data = {u'jobs': {u'_total': 301746, u'_count': 10, u'_start': 0, u'values': [{u'position':       {u'title': u'Director of Sales, New York '}, u'id': 7489651}, {u'position': {u'title': u'Senior Software Development Engineer'}, u'id': 7489610}, {u'position': {u'title': u'Senior Analyst, Marketing Analytics'}, u'id': 7489572}, {u'position': {u'title': u'Director,  Quantitative Analytics'}, u'id': 7489559}, {u'position': {u'title': u'Senior Quantitative Analyst'}, u'id': 7489542}, {u'position': {u'title': u'Director - Progam Lead and Project Manager - Collateral Management'}, u'id': 7489520}, {u'position': {u'title': u'Accounting and Finance Manager'}, u'id': 7489519}, {u'position': {u'title': u'Software Development Engineer - Test'}, u'id': 7489508}, {u'position': {u'title': u'Sr. Sales Executive - Technology'}, u'id': 7489462}, {u'position': {u'title': u'Recruitment Manager'}, u'id': 7489264}]}}

pprint(data['jobs']['values'])
```

prints a list of dictionaries:

```
[{u'id': 7489651, u'position': {u'title': u'Director of Sales, New York '}},
 {u'id': 7489610,
  u'position': {u'title': u'Senior Software Development Engineer'}},
 {u'id': 7489572,
  u'position': {u'title': u'Senior Analyst, Marketing Analytics'}},
 {u'id': 7489559,
  u'position': {u'title': u'Director,  Quantitative Analytics'}},
 {u'id': 7489542, u'position': {u'title': u'Senior Quantitative Analyst'}},
 {u'id': 7489520,
  u'position': {u'title': u'Director - Progam Lead and Project Manager - Collateral Management'}},
 {u'id': 7489519, u'position': {u'title': u'Accounting and Finance Manager'}},
 {u'id': 7489508,
  u'position': {u'title': u'Software Development Engineer - Test'}},
 {u'id': 7489462,
  u'position': {u'title': u'Sr. Sales Executive - Technology'}},
 {u'id': 7489264, u'position': {u'title': u'Recruitment Manager'}}]
```

Comment: You already made it long enough to meet the minimum requirement for a valid SO answer, and to say everything there is to say, and yet you're still editing. :)

Comment: @abarnert I think this is called `perfectionism` :) But, you know, I can make it worse :)